# How to brute force inputs into a exe?

Tags: reverse-engineering, brute-force

So I have this exe hash generator in which I have to find the string which generates a given specific hash. Since I know the length of the string I was wondering maybe I can brute force inputs into the executable. Or alternatively can someone tell me how to reverse engineer the whole exe to find out how it generates the hash.

Comment: Keep it simple? Learn x86 assembly and use OllyDbg to examine/step into the executable code of your program so you can study it and eventually, reverse engineer it. Simple to say, very hard to actually do it.

Comment: well my input string is 13 characters long.And I have the hash that will be generated after entering the string what I want to know is what is the string. Cause I have its length, the hash it will generate and the program that generates the hash.

Comment: you could pipe a custom string generator and redirect the std output of your exe  in a text file

Comment: I am sorry @Seb but I didn't understand a word you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom program to generate strings you want to test (C#)

```
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\keys.txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    // Replace this line by the string you want to test
                    var str = Guid.NewGuid();
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                    sw.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

then, use command redirection to redirect the output of that console App to your EXE file.  (see https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)  don't forget to redirect your exe output to a text file if you want to keep the results

```
consoleAppCs.exe | YourExe.exe > "C:\temp\output.txt"
```

then you will have two text files to compare in the `c:\temp\` folder